# Text that get pushed down and truncated by amount of text above

Tags: html, css

I want to accomplish something rather complex. I've made an image to explain it better:

[image]

1. The title text can be a maximum of 3 lines
2. The text below that can be a maximum of 5 lines
3. The text below should be longer or shorter, depended on the title text above it
4. If one of the texts is too long, the text should get truncated with ellipses

How do I accomplish this in HTML/CSS? 
I already found something for truncating with ellipses: http://jsfiddle.net/6hk8Ldq2/

```js
  var p=$('#fos p');
    var divh=$('#fos').height();
    while ($(p).outerHeight()>divh) {
        $(p).text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add ellipses on multiline text then you have to use `-webkit-line-clamp` with number of line as a value (`3`, `4`, `5`) and also below styles.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

I also have added jQuery code to calculate `-webkit-line-clamp` value dynamically.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(window).on('resize', resetHeight)

function resetHeight(){
  $(".fos").each(function(){
    $(this).find("p").height($(this).height() - $(this).find(".title").height() - 10);

    /*var lineheight = parseFloat($(this).find("p").css('line-height'));
    var scrollheight = parseFloat($(this).find("p").height()); 
    var calc = parseInt(scrollheight/lineheight) + 1;
    
    calc = (calc>5)?5:calc;*/
    
    
    var title=$(this).find(".title");
    var divh=$(this).find(".title").height()+10;
    
    while ($(title)[0].scrollHeight>divh) {
        $(title).text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
    
    
    $(this).find("p").addClass("p-overflow");
    //$(this).find("p").css({"-webkit-line-clamp": "" + calc + ""});
    var p=$(this).find("p");
    var divh=$(this).find("p").height()+10;
    
    while ($(p)[0].scrollHeight>divh) {
        $(p).text(function (index, text) {
            return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
        });
    }
  });
}
$("#textHeight").change(function(){
 $(".fos").height($(this).val());
 $(".fos").css("max-height", $(this).val() + "px");
  //resetHeight();
});

resetHeight();
```

```css
*{
  font-family: calibri;
}
.changeHeight{
  padding:10px 5px;
}
.fos-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.fos {
  width: 220px; 
  min-height: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:#eee;
  padding:10px;
  font-family: calibri;
  margin:5px;
}
.fos .title{
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-height:58px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp:3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
  overflow:hidden;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.fos p { 
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  line-height:19.5px;
}

.p-overflow {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="changeHeight">
  <label for="textHeight">Change .fos height: </label><input id="textHeight" name="textHeight" type="number" min="120" max="420" step="20" value="120"/>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="fos-container">

  <div class="fos">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Lorem ipsum</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a lacus sodales eleifend. Vestibulum lorem felis, rhoncus elementum vestibulum eget, dictum ut velit. Nullam venenatis, elit in suscipit imperdiet, orci purus posuere mauris, quis adipiscing ipsum urna ac quam.</p> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="fos">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="fos">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui</div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a lacus sodales eleifend. Vestibulum lorem felis, rhoncus elementum vestibulum eget, dictum ut velit. Nullam venenatis, elit in suscipit imperdiet, orci purus posuere mauris, quis adipiscing ipsum urna ac quam.</p> 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/65rw197t/) also.

**Update 1**

Limit the text below to maximum 5 lines.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/65rw197t/2/)

**Update 2**

I have merged the original code to the solution so that it will work on Firefox as well.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/65rw197t/15/)

Comment: Thanks! I've played around with your Fiddle a bit. It doesn't seem to limit the amount of the text below. Those shouldn't be allowed to be more than 5 lines. Unfortunately also the ellipses don't seem to work on Firefox.

Comment: That's right, it won't work on Firefox as Firefox doesn't support this feature for now. For the first question, you can add the condition for the `-webkit-line-clamp` if the value goes beyond the 5, set it to 5.

Comment: Just curious, isn't it possible to combine the script in my question with your script to achieve ellipsis on every browser? Because that script seems to work on Firefox.

Comment: I have updated the answer snippet as well as jsfiddle. Added your code in my solution to make it compatible on Firefox.. I must say running a while loop is not a good solution. :)

Comment: Thanks! It's not working on the title but I can live with that. Why is running a while loop not a good idea?

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot to add it on title.. We are removing characters/word one by one till it reaches in the boundary.. If the `paragraph` has very long text then it will be a time consuming. Also keep in mind, we are running it for 3 `paragraphs`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183017/discussion-between-gerlof-leuhof-and-nimit-shah).